# Store utf-8 in string variable

Tags: string

I know it is possible to store utf-8 text in string variable.

but it gives error.

```
contract test1{
    string text = "ğğğğ şşşş üüüü";
 }
```

[image]

Comment: Can you post your contract code? This will allow to provide more detailed help.

Comment: Actually its a blank contract just to test variable types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is related to unicode encoding. The characters that you are using are not supported by the default ASCII encoding. To fix this you can use the `unicode` prefix:

```js
contract test1{
  string text = unicode"ğğğğ şşşş üüüü";
}
```

this is documented here: https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.11/types.html?highlight=unicode#unicode-literals

Comment: I just started reading that document, havent reached there yet.  Thank you.